# unable to upload picture on MySQL connected with google cloud app engine in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I deploy a Laravel project on google cloud app engine.

Am trying to upload a picture that will save in the 'public/uploads' folder of the laravel project, in product table of MySQL database connected with google cloud app engine.

It's working on my localhost but not on google cloud.

Here's the image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write to the production server in the cloud.  From: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#filesystem

> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> write to the filesystem. PHP applications can use Google Cloud Storage
> for storing persistent files. Reading from the filesystem is allowed,
> and all application files uploaded with the application are available.

You want to use Google Cloud Storage to upload photos.  You can write to the `/tmp` directory temporarily, but that will not persist.

Comment: Am trying to upload the picture via code to my gcs bucket and now am stuck at this error:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16lWL-odrrlYrY9fbLE20F_oxXQfANl2X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you set up permissions on your bucket so that your app can access?

Comment: by bad bucket, name wasn't correct. 
The image is in the bucket now. ^_^
One more help from you please :)
Now that picture will save in the SQL and GCS bucket.
How can I access that file? 

Comment: Did you try: `https://storage.googleapis.com/yourbucket.appspot.com/yourimagepath.jpg`?

Comment: in the image column, the image is saved as 

"ufurnitures-img/vC9Kr7I9FTJmclIhAvEq3ntOVtoTUq7Wyv2vHsjh.jpeg"

in the bucket when I hover over the image am getting this link it's downloading the file

"https://storage.googleapis.com/ufurnitures-img/phpK3xYn2"

How can I show that image to my frontend?

Comment: `<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ufurnitures-img/vC9Kr7I9FTJmclIhAvEq3ntOVtoTUq7Wyv2vHsjh.jpeg">`  You should set better filenames when uploading

Comment: I just hardcore that src still unable to access that picture.
Here's the error am getting:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WU0YbQiD_SZ9HdH9gZ3Syp2nTHTzQdQq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check your permissions on that file.  To access via URL, it will need to have Public permissions (AllUsers: Read).  Also, a screenshot of your bucket with path would help

Comment: Here's the screenshot of bucket:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EcpG8I0DI4UDhfF7fJFo9zqwBRsBT43b/view?usp=sharing

Here's the screenshot of bucket permission:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12U8jQeWGjqBqBNzIdE_9L54XE0nFrpUR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to put file extensions on these, but one is accessible at: https://storage.googleapis.com/ufurnitures-img/php7Dxe6b. Without the file extension, the browser can't handle it.  I have to get back to work.  Bye

Comment: Hi again, 
As you told me I had changed the name of the images that saved in DB but am unable to store the image in the bucket with extension.
I can store without extension but I want to save it with extension here's the screenshot of the code.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14IVtDt4fN3ybGZ-FI2zU6Z3z0SCW1KsU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is a separate question.  Please accept the answer, then open a new question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the uploads directory doesn't have write permissions.
You can go to the file manager and change the permissions to 755 i.e. "read and execute access for everyone" or simply execute the following command using the command line.

`$chmod 755 /var/www/html/public/system`

`$chown www-data:www-data`.

Comment: There's no www in the var folder. :/
Please check the attached image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14q5jRLX7M06gW6XjZBjk9iqAMpuIiU3Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Go to your laravel project directory <laravel project>/public then run command relatively in that folder.
```$chmod 755 <laravel project>/public```