# The directory is not writable by the Web process: /app/backend/web/assets'

Tags: google-app-engine, yii2

i'm deploying my app in google app engine when below error appear where can i get permissions from app engine to write to assets folder?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EpfI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to upload picture on MySQL connected with google cloud app engine in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814379/unable-to-upload-picture-on-mysql-connected-with-google-cloud-app-engine-in-lara)

Comment: I am not looking to give permissions to my folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate question.  You cannot write to the production server in the cloud. From: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#filesystem

> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> write to the filesystem. Applications can use Google Cloud Storage
> for storing persistent files. Reading from the filesystem is allowed,
> and all application files uploaded with the application are available.

You want to use Google Cloud Storage to upload photos. You can write to the /tmp directory temporarily, but that will not persist.

Answer (score 0):

You can not write files to the local filesystem of your App Engine app except for the `/tmp` directory (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#filesystem_2)).

However, bear in mind that the `/tmp` directory stores the data temporarily in the memory of the instance. This means that other instances that run your GAE app won't have access to the stored data.

If you need to persist files, you should [use Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/using-cloud-storage)